# Converting a S3 Bucket folder contents into a list in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I haven't spotted a post about this topic relevant to Rails, but if you've seen it please send it my way.

I'm trying to list certain files from my S3 bucket which has a structure like this:

**S3 Bucket > Datev_Documents > 2021 > Months 1-12 > Each month contains the relevant files.**

I would like to recreate that same view, perhaps only from the Year(s) folder and it's children, in a Rails Page.

So far my view looks like this:

```
    h1 Datev File List

ul
  - [2020, 2021].each do |y|

    li
      h2 = y.to_s
      ul
        - (1..12).each do |m|
          li
            h3 = m.to_s.rjust(2, "0")
            ul
              - ["File 1", "File 2", "File 3"].each do |f|
                li = f
```

I'm not sure how best to tackle this, I thought maybe by generating a list of all the files I want in the bucket itself:

```
 def list_bucket_objects(s3_resource, bucket_name)
        puts s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).objects(prefix: '2020/4/', delimiter: '/').collect(&:key)
      end
```

But how do I go about translating this to a list view, organised by file YYYYY/MM?

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!